# Upgrade URL for SEO from example.com/dbtable_id/ to example.com/dbtable_id/article-title

Tags: seo

I have an existing journal website with the following url structure

```
http://example.com/dbtable_id/
(eg. http://example.com/89348/)
```

where 89348 is the primary key id of the journal article.

I want to add the title of the article to the url for SEO purposes like

```
http://example.com/dbtable_id/article-title
(eg. http://example.com/89348/hello-world)
```

I like this approach because I don't need to change the PHP code since it will still look up the article by dbtable_id.  All I have to do is append url friendly titles to relevant links in template files and add one more rule to a .htaccess file.

Is there anything I should be concerned about?  Am I following best practices?  Will the possibility for mismatch between "dbtable_id" and "article-title" affect SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some that argue that shallow paths are better than deeper paths, but I don't put too much stock in this. A semantic page with a screwed up URL will always do better than an unsemantic page with a "perfect" URL.

So i say, go for it. As long as it doesn't have any querystring parameters, you should be fine.